# Old laptop for Ubuntu home server: powerful enough?

Tags: server, dell, hardware

It's main use will be:

- Torrents and other downloads
- Storing files (everything, from jpgs to big ISOs) from multiple Ubuntu, Android and Windows systems (more than 7)
- Streaming 1080p video files (around 2100+ Kbps bitrate) to those devices and a SmartTV

Nothing too crazy, but there's the hardware: the laptop is an old Inspiron 6400 with a Core Duo (not 2, the original) with 1GB of RAM and a 965 chipset. It already runs Ubuntu and other apps *decently*, but its not fast.

I have a N router but the laptop has a G card. I guess I could change it, or in any case wire it to the router, although that could be difficult because the router is in a place with little space.

Besides that I plan to connect 2 1TB 2.5" USB HDDs to it for storage, but I'm not sure if it could power a third one, would welcome some input on this.

So, can it handle this?

Comment: 1) What do you expect from it? In absolute terms, like transfer rates. 2) What kind of files are you going to store? 3) What kind of video files? HD high bitrate? 4) Does it need to do transcoding of just streaming the raw files? 5) What have you tried in the current Ubuntu installation?

Comment: What do you mean with streaming? Are you referring to install a DLNA server?

Comment: Added the details. By streaming I mean playing that video file from the server without transferring it to the device in question.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you need a DLNA server with support for transcoding on the fly, I do not see any tasks needing a powerful processor.

I have an Atom server doing similar tasks and the machine has very low levels of load. With such tasks, your processor will be idle most of the time.